# replace with instanced collections

Tags: collections, instances, origin

Ok...
I have an imported fb, lots of separate mesh, all needing to be separated (editmode/mouse over+L/P and repeat) a majority of the mesh items are the same. I would like to model  a simpler geometry, as the original FBX is a tech render from rhino with dirty mesh... so remodeling items in blender and replace... its a routine that I do often, but I need to stream line more, and have questions.

if my created instance is on the orgin point (0,0,0) with the rotation 0'd as well... is there an easy routine to match the rotation and position of the fbx originals... mainly to match the rotation... the position is easy as they are spherical objects with an easy set origin, but this still leaves me with the guesswork of rotation. but I think its an impossible feet, but I thought I would throw it out there and see if I was overlooking something.

Comment: Hello :). You could make a custom orientation from the original (.fbx imported) mesh, and then apply it to your instance. Please add some images to illustrate your issue.